# Trigger Activities overview at key press instead of release

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, activities-overview

I want to know if it is possible to change the activation of the Activities overview via a key press instead of a key release.

When I'm switching workspaces quickly I usually do this via key combinations from <kbd>Super_L</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to <kbd>Super_L</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> for the 5 static workspaces I have.

However, sometimes I forgot where I put applications and change to the wrong workspace. In order to switch fast and have a quick overview, it would be great to have the Activities overview pop up already at a press of <kbd>Super_L</kbd>.
Right now, to get the overview I need to first press and release <kbd>Super_L</kbd> until the overview pops up and then I need to switch with e.g. <kbd>Super_L</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to the third workspace. With a press it would be possible to hold down <kbd>Super_L</kbd> until the overlay pops out and then just press the additional number.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea, all the `Super`+`other key` combinations would likely be badly affected by this change.

Comment: Anytime you hit `Super`, the overview would appear indeed. Instead you may consider using `Super`+`s` to display the overview while your are holding the `Super`key.

Comment: That is a much better solution then what I'm currently doing. I was not aware of the `Super` + `s` key combination.

Comment: @pomsky and Invarianz, at your service ;) I have also been switching workspaces this way, "i3" style, for a while :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be a good idea to trigger Activities overview with <kbd>Super</kbd> at key press instead of release. If you could do it without breaking the function of <kbd>Super</kbd> as a modifier key, then also pressing it with another key would switch to the overview each time.

Instead, you may consider using the default keybinding <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to switch to the overview. The existence of that shortcut also will allow you to just keep the <kbd>Super</kbd> key pressed, and move workspaces within the overview with the number keys. Hit <kbd>s</kbd> again (or press <kbd>Esc</kbd>) to land on your workspace.

*Some bonus tips*

- Discover <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> that takes you to the application overview.
- If you find that the <kbd>Super</kbd> alone sometimes triggers you to the overview by accident, then disable it with the command `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''`.